# QT подключение и чтение serialPort

Tags: c++, qt, serialport

Подключаюсь к порту , читаю данные всё норм, Но есть 2 момента не приятных:

1. Если происходит отключение от порта отлавливаю `SerialPortError` получаю ошибку и все, при повторном коннекте ничего не происходит, данную проблему пока решил циклом `while`:

   ```cpp
   void MySerialPort::openDefault()
   {
       serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
       serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
       serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
       serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
       serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
       serial.setPortName("COM3");
       serial.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly);
   }

   void MySerialPort::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
   {
       if ((serial.isOpen()) && (error == QSerialPort::DeviceNotFoundError ||
                                 error == QSerialPort::PermissionError ||
                                 error == QSerialPort::ResourceError))
       {
           emit disconnected();
           serial.close();
           while (!serial.isOpen())
           {
               openDefault();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   но окно программы тогда зависает пока не подключиться к порту, как это исправить?
2. Если программа уже запущена и я во время её работы подсоединяю USB, чтение данных не
   происходит, как начать читать данные, после подсоединения к USB ?

Comment: Вроде в доках есть пример использования компорта, поищите

Comment: У меня была похожая проблема с `Boost.Asio`. Там нужно было вызвать что-то для `io_context`. Думаю, что тут нужно тоже что-то резетнуть.

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать `clear` и/либо `clearError`

Comment: а как окно будет работать, если вы блокируете обработку сообщений? запустите таймер, по истечении пробуйте открыть опять

Comment: про таймер забыл, попробую как нибудь его использовать, чтоб работал всегда и каждые секунд 10 перепроверял, подключение....

Comment: У вас при дисконнекте скорее всего должен сигнал испуститься `QSerialPort::errorOccurred`